# Kafka config chroot in zookeeper.connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I want to use *chroot* in *zookeeper* for *Kafka* data. So I set the following config in **server.properties**:

```
zookeeper.connect=10.114.0.2:2181/kafka,10.114.0.3:2181/kafka,10.114.0.4:2181/kafka
```

But it does not work and I see the wrong path in zookeeper:

[image]

How can I use chroot for kafka to save all kafka data in `/kafka` in zookeeper?

P.S.: my Kafka version is **3.1.0**

Answer (score 2):

Found it.

We must just add *chroot* directory at the end of connection string like below:

```
zookeeper.connect=10.114.0.2:2181,10.114.0.3:2181,10.114.0.4:2181/kafka
```